# How I retrieve objects that match the userid in swift/parse?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I retrieve an item that is in the same row as a particular userid in parse to swift?
They are both in the same custom class

right now the code retrieve all all items. i would like to filter them according to userid/username

```
extension reservedCust {
class func userWithUserId(userid userid : String) -> reservedCust? {
    let query = reservedCust.query();
    query?.whereKey("userid", equalTo: userid);
    var userssss : [PFObject]?

    do {
        userssss = try query?.findObjects();
    }
    catch {
        return nil;
    }

    if userssss?.count > 0 {
        return userssss?[0] as? reservedCust;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

`}`

`class itemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {`

```
var itemList = [String]()
var userid = [String]()
var names = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let user = reservedCust.userWithUserId(userid : "your UserID") {
        //do you stuff with retrieved user


    let query = PFQuery(className:"reservedCust")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {


                    if let item = object["item"] as? String {

                        self.itemList.append((object["item"] as? String)!)

                    }



                }


            }

            print(self.itemList)
            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }else {

        }
    }

}


}
```

Comment: its genuine question . you guys are not helping

Comment: do you have data of logged in user ? how you are getting useid ?

Comment: i have saved userid and items in a new class. now i want to retire the items that are related to a particular class. say userid "e" has selected items "n","m","b". how do i display those items that he selected

Answer (score 0):

```
extension reservedCust {
    class func userWithUserId(userID userID : String) -> reservedCust? {
        let query = reservedCust.query();
        query?.whereKey("userID", equalTo: userID);
        var userssss : [PFObject]?

        do {
            userssss = try query?.findObjects();
        }
        catch {
            return nil;
        }

        if userssss?.count > 0 {
            return userssss?[0] as? reservedCust;
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

**Assumtions:** 
**1)** You should paste above extension code, out side the body of your calss.
**2)** Your userID column name is userID other wise replace the string "userID" of line `query?.whereKey("userID", equalTo: userID);` with your column name, so it will be `query?.whereKey("your column name for userID field", equalTo: userID);`

**Use:**

```
if let user = reservedCust.userWithUserId(userID : "your UserID") {
       //do you stuff with retrieved user
}
```

**You `viewDidLoad` will be:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let user = reservedCust.userWithUserId(userid : "your UserID") {
            //do you stuff with retrieved user

            //your core logic depends on item is string or array or whatever
            if let item = user["item"] as? String {

                    self.itemList.append((user["item"] as? String)!)

            }


           print(self.itemList)
           self.tableView.reloadData(

            }else {

            }
        }
```

Comment: hi I've posted my code below. could you see what i can do to it

Comment: @iosmadness about your answer, it will get all the items of all the rows of table reservedCust or class reservedCust,

Comment: yea. please can u suggest how i filter them to the userid?

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a noob but where do i add this code to check?

Comment: add extenstion code above your class definition, and add ==Use:== code in your viewDidLoad or the place where you want to test this.

Comment: hi hitendra i have edited the code in my question.i get undeclared resolver errors. the code is in my question

Comment: i am getting undeclared identifier error. i tried till now.

Comment: At which line you are getting error ? can you please add the code of your parse class